# findbug warning on my android application singleton

Tags: singleton, android

I appreciate the pros/cons of singletons in Android and the various arguments for them and for creating singleton instance of an object or the application itself, but it fulfills my need to have a single instance of my Database Manager facade available to the application.

After searching various places for the best approach I found the following code. But findbugs doesn't really like my assignment of 'this' to the static instance.

This class doesn't fully follow the standard singleton approach but supposedly was a better way based on the knowledge that there is only ever one Application created and the order of method calls are known. Can anyone tell me if this code is wrong or let me know how to get around the findbug issue, if it is actually an issue. I've highlighted the bug line.

My source for the code was:
http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=9A77FA007453433B9F15F792396B744F?recipeId=1218&recipeFrom=ViewTOC

```
public class DatabaseApplication extends Application {

private static DatabaseApplication instance;  //the single instance of this app

private DataManager dataManager; //the database facade, again a single instance

public static DatabaseApplication getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

/**
 * onCreate will always be called before this.
 * 
 * @return data manager, effectively a singleton too
 */
public DataManager getDataManager() {
    return dataManager;
}

/*
 * onCreate only called when app is created by the system
 * 
 * @see android.app.Application#onCreate()
 */
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

           //Bug: Write to static field 
           //DatabaseApplication.instance from instance method                     
           //DatabaseApplication.onCreate()
    instance = this; 

    instance.initializeInstance();
}

/**
 * Create the one and only dataManager
 */
protected void initializeInstance() {
    dataManager = new DataManager(this, false);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the warning/error message you are getting from findbug?

Comment: So mark it to be skipped; what's the issue?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the var with DatabaseApplication.instance? You are accessing it like a normal instance var and FindBugs might warn you just to be sure you know it is a class member.

Comment: @Leco, the warning is in the code next to the 'instance = this'. Yes I could skip it, I was just asking if it's being set incorrectly or if there's a better way.